# The query has been canceled because the estimated cost of this query exceeds the configured threshold

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

> The query has been canceled because the estimated cost of this query (1660) exceeds the configured threshold of 1500. Contact the system administrator.

I am getting error as above on live while running one of the stored procedure threads where parameter contain XML variable.

I have checked the configuration value of `QUERY_GOVERNOR_COST_LIMIT` is set to 1500.
To get resolve this problem I have added `SET QUERY_GOVERNOR_COST_LIMIT 0` in stored procedures. And it is working fine.

When I run stored procedures in back end with and without `SET QUERY_GOVERNOR_COST_LIMIT 0` statement, it is running fine, and run within 0 seconds.
But it is creating problem with .Net application and getting error.

So, why it is giving error with application and not with SQL Query analyzer?
Even query is run within 0 seconds as it can give error when execution time will exceed more then 15 seconds (as configured  `QUERY_GOVERNOR_COST_LIMIT 1500` )?

Please share your idea for the analysis and solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could be because SET ARITHABORT is OFF from .NET

could also be  a conversion problem, look at your execution plan do you see any conversions. How are you executing this from .NET and are you using the correct data types?

Answer (score 0):

usually this happens because of different default ANSI setting for SSMS and .net
they could create different execution plans.
the first you need to check is the execution plans from both sources.
you can do this with sql profiler's [Showplan XML event](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190233.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

`QUERY_GOVERNOR_COST_LIMIT` is a connection level Runtime setting. So while making connection this needs to be set. When you test in SSMS Query window you need to set this setting in QueryOption property window (right click inside query window, QueryOptions, Advance,...)

You also mentioned that query executes in 0 seconds so why even from .NET it errors out with setting of 15sec? Because the setting works on Estimated Query execution Cost, not the Actual one. So right question is why sql server has estimated the execution cost more than 15sec.? And there is no single answer for this one.

Though I would like to know what is the user workflow/situation where you actually need to use this setting. Many times estimated cost is lot different than actual so unless dev/dba know exactly what they are doing and what will be execution... looks like I don't understand the practical usage of this setting.